# pandas write dataframe to_json method alternative

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe

I'm processing a dataframe with about 4 million rows and 50 columns every hour using this:

```
    #Write out the file
    try:
        display('Writing {0} '.format(filename))
        df_full.to_json('{0}{1}'.format(output_path,filename),orient='records',lines=True )
    except Exception as e :
        logging.error("Error could not write file", exc_info=True)
        print("Error could not write file")
```

I did this out of simplicity but its so slow. It doesnt seem like any IO bottle neck , but I must write out to json as this is fed into another system for pickup/ingest.  What would be a faster alternative method?

Comment: I've noticed that iterating over the lines is usually faster, try this: https://pastebin.com/Rm4qhJEm

Comment: still a bit slow but I believe it is better

Comment: Yeah there's not much you can do with IO, especially with that volume of data. What is the difference in timings?

Comment: its actually not faster haha or at least not in this case. Ran the code side by side df.to_json is was faster than running the loop as described. I put timers around the write writes.. oh well.